# error CS0012: The type 'TaskAwaiter<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

When I try to debug my Windows Phone 8.1 project the Locals window is empty, and Watch shows an error for `this`:

```
this    error CS0012: The type 'TaskAwaiter<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Everything else seems to work just fine, there are no errors/warnings related to this, it happens only while debuging. And also not for all projects.

I've tried a few fixes I found on Stack and MDSN, but:

- Adding `<CheckForSystemRuntimeDependency>true</CheckForSystemRuntimeDependency>` didn't change anything;
- Debug > Options > General > Use legacy VB and C# something is greyed out.

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a known issue in Visual Studio 2015.

Workaround: enable the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators. (You got that right.)

*Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators*

**Important: You cannot check the box during debugging!**

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about this anymore since it was greyed out, but yeah, now that I checked options without debugging it worked.

Comment: The workaround worked for me too, but only after I uninstalled my app from the phone. Cleaning and building wasn't enough.

Comment: Why, Microsoft, why?