# windows phone 8.1 call rest api c#

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing one `windows phone 8.1` app. In this app I required to call restful apis. Here is my api call method

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> callrestApi(string baseurl, string api, string method, string contenttype, object objPost)
{
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(contenttype));

            switch (method.ToLower())
            {
                case "get":
                    // HTTP GET
                    response = await client.GetAsync(api);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        object obj = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        //return obj;
                    }
                    break;
                case "post":
                    // HTTP POST
                    response = await client.PostAsync(api, new StringContent(objPost.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, contenttype));
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        object obj = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        //return obj;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am calling this method from **MainPage.xaml** for login. I am passing json obj with username and password.

```
var resp = await Constants.callrestApi(Constants.base_Url, Constants.apiList.loginApi, Constants.httpmethod.post, Constants.contenttype.json, jsonObj);
if (resp != null)
{

}
```

When I debug this I am getting following error

> error CS0012: The type 'HttpResponseMessage' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
>   You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I think the problem is in `await` call. How can I call restful api?

Answer (score 1):

In the description of the error it says that you have not added the assembly named `System.Net.Http` to your references. Just try to right-click on the references [image 1] of your app and select `Add reference`. Find `System.Net.Http` in the list of Frameworks and add it to your project [image 2].

[image: References image]
[image]

**[EDITED FROM HERE]**

Since that is not the issue, I have put together a small example of a method that calls a REST API (async). Let me know if this works for you, and if not provide some more details about the API.

```
public async Task<string> callRestAPI(string serviceURL)
{
    var getRequest = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, serviceURL);

    var postRequest = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, serviceURL);
    postRequest.Content = new StringContent("string data");

    using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        var getResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(getRequest);
        var postResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(postRequest);
        var getData = await getResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var postData = await postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine(getData);
        Debug.WriteLine(postData);

        return getData;
    }
}
```

I am calling the method just for testing in the `OnNavigatedTo` method as follows:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

    // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
    // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
    // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
    // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
    // this event is handled for you.

    var testResult = await callRestAPI("~your URL here~");
}
```

Comment: I am targeting  windows phone 8.1.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried it. But not working. Giving error `error CS0012: The type 'TaskAwaiter<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

Comment: Something seems very strange... What version of visual studio are you using? How did you create the project?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015 pro. NewProject -> C# -> windows -> Pivot App(Windows phone 8.1)

Comment: As far as I know the pivot app is for silverlight only. That is a different SDK and therefore the errors. Try to create a project using C# -> Windows 8 -> Phone (or something like that, I don't remember exactly)

Comment: Have you managed to solve your problem? :-) Do you need further assistance?

Comment: I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053129/error-cs0012-the-type-taskawaiter-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-ref

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `Microsoft.Net.Http` NuGet package for Windows Phone (and other platforms as well). You can find the package information here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/

Either add this via command line or right click on the project, then select `Manage NuGet Packages`, then search for `Microsoft.Net.Http` and finally select `Install`.

Using the package manager console you can use the following command to add this package to your project.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http
```